How to display counter text in English for TextInputLayout in a multilingual Android app
Description:
I'm using a TextInputLayout with TextInputEditText to allow users to enter text in my Android app. I've enabled the character counter with a maximum length of 500, so as the user types, the counter displays the number of characters entered. Here’s the issue:
My app supports multiple languages, including languages like Bengali and Marathi, which enforce their own numerals based on the system's locale. As a result, the counter text for characters entered appears in Bengali or Marathi numerals when the device is set to these languages. However, I want to keep the counter text (numbers) in English, regardless of the system language, for consistency across the app.
What I've Tried:

I attempted to change the locale context for just the counter view to English. This partially works, as the counter initially displays in the local language (e.g., Bengali), but after typing, it switches to English. This inconsistent behavior is not ideal, as the counter should always remain in English.
Here’s the XML for my TextInputLayout:


<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/post_edit_text_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_border_post"
    android:padding="8dp"
    app:boxBackgroundMode="none"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    app:counterMaxLength="500"
    app:counterTextColor="@color/textColorSecondary"
    app:hintEnabled="false">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/post_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxHeight="200dp"
        android:minLines="6"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
        android:textColorHint="@color/textColorSecondary"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

How can I ensure that the character counter always displays numbers in English, regardless of the system language, in a consistent way?
Is there a way to override the locale specifically for the counter text in TextInputLayout without affecting other parts of the layout? Or I am going about it the Wrong way?!

Try setting an English font for the counter specifically

could u give me an example on how i could do that?!

@Shubham Is the counter a textview?

no, counter is the property of TextInputLayout. which automatically inc and decr acc. to no character

Yes! you can disable that translation setting in regional languages. You are using XML views, and I suppose that you use the string.xml files.

Go to strings



Open one of them and click on "Open editor"


Finally, you should be sure that "Untranslatable" option is marked.




The counter isn't string resourse that i have created, so I can't untranslate it
